# How to SELECT top different value using order by matrics

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this

[image]

i want to get the row of each table that have min responsetime

i have tried this query :

```
select tablename,
       index1, 
       index2, 
       min(responsetime) 
from   tableconf 
group by tablename 
order by responsetime asc
```

but it doesn't give what i want

the output that i want is

```
+------------------+------------------+--------+--------------+
|    tablename     |     index1       | index2 | responsetime |
+------------------+------------------+--------+--------------+
| salesorderheader | TotalDue         | NULL   |       6.1555 |
| salesterritory   | Name             | NULL   |     11.66667 |
| store            | BusinessEntityId | Name   |       3.6222 |
| previous         | previous         | NULL   |      5.03333 |
| NONE             | NONE             | NULL   |          5.6 |
+------------------+------------------+--------+--------------+
```

what query i should use for get the output that i want

Comment: How are you deciding what `index1` and `index2` values to pick for your grouping?

Comment: @Siyual: It's the whole record with the minimum response time per table name.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ah, misread the requirement.  I see.

Comment: What is the output you geht? What is the undesired difference? [Mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the minimum date per table name. Use an `IN` clause on these to get the rows:

```
select *
from tableconf 
where (tablename, responsetime) in
(
  select tablename, min(responsetime)
  from tableconf 
  group by tablename
);
```

Comment: thankyou this is works!, but how to limiting the value of table name that have same minimun response time into just one row?

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Answer (score -1):

(Edited from previous answer)

I don't know if all SQL syntax accept a comma separated where parameter. Another option building off of the highest voted answer right now utilizes a join:

```
select *
from tableconf t
inner join (
           select tablename, min(responsetime) min_rt
           from tableconf t2
           group by tablename
           ) t3 on t.tablename = t2.tablename and t.responsetime = t2.min_rt
```

Comment: This will lead to duplicates in the groups due to the different index values.

Comment: i have tried this but it gives me more than one row that have tablename value 'store'